# Print documents using Ubuntu server and openbox

Tags: server, printing, openbox

I'm running Ubuntu server with Openbox on an old computer -- everything is running smoothly.

Supposing I got a PDF document or so, how can I print it to the printer?

I guess I have to install something first to configure the printer. What program should I install (probably via `apt-get`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add printers using `lpadmin` from `cups-client` package. Take a look for this [tutorial](http://blog.ostermiller.org/ubuntu-printer-install-command-line/).

to print you can use one of these two commands`lpr` and `lp`:

Install `lpr`:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-bsd
```

Install `lp`:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client
```

Now you can use it easily:

```
lp /path-to-file-to-print
```

Or

```
lpr /path-to-file-to-print
```

Take a look for `man lp` and `man lpr` for more information

Comment: I suppose I have to `apt-get install cups-client` first, right?

Comment: When I run `lp`, I get `lp: Error - scheduler not responding.`.

Comment: what about lpr?

Comment: `$ lpr 
The program 'lpr' can be found in the following packages:
 * cups-bsd
 * gnuspool
 * lpr
 * lprngTry: sudo apt-get install <selected package>` -- which to install?

Comment: check edit, sudo apt-get install cups-bsd

Comment: Note that I mentioned before that I didn't make any setup about printer on the computer. On Unity I have that little tool to install the printer.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Ok check the edit now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25809/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-maythux).